# CA1822: Mark members as static, when used in different assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting this warning in vscode:

> Member 'GetNumber' does not access instance data and can be marked as static (Roslyn (CA1822))

The thing is, `GetNumber` is actually used by another assembly and marking it as static would break things badly. I've read the [documentation for CA1822](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1822) and also [the documentation for how to disable warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings), so I'm aware I could disable the warnings using any of these options:

1. setting its severity to none in an EditorConfig or AnalyzerConfig configuration file
2. Use a preprocessor directive such as `#pragma warning disable CA1822`
3. Use the `SuppressMessageAttribute`

I'm not very happy with any of these options, hence my questions:

1. Why can't the Roslyn compiler in vscode detect that the method is being used in another assembly?

I have a solution file that references both assemblies, couldn't that be used to detect how methods from one assembly are being used by the other?

2. Is suppressing the warning my only option?

Comment: If a compiler was responsible for checking if everything it compiled was ever used in any other assembly ever, it would never finish compiling...

Comment: I'm not asking it to check every assembly ever, I'm asking it to check the few assemblies I have referenced in my solution.

Comment: How does marking the method as static break things badly? Can you elaborate?

Comment: `GetNumber` is a method from my HotChocolate GraphQL Query type. Marking it as static makes it so that the method is no longer registered as a GraphQL resolver. I'm not exactly sure why it has this limitation, but I figured the issue wasn't specific to HotChocolate anyway.

Comment: What happens if you add the `[PublicAPI]` attribute to the function?

Comment: [PublicAPI] seems to be from the Visual Studio ReSharper extension? I don't use Visual Studio so this isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't the Roslyn compiler in vscode detect that the method is being used in another assembly?
> I have a solution file that references both assemblies, couldn't that be used to detect how methods from one assembly are being used by the other?

What you are asking for might be totally doable; it might even be on the todo list. But the people working on the Roslyn compiler only have 24 hours a day (or 25 if they decide to work during lunch).

> Is suppressing the warning my only option?

It presently is. Even, possibly, the correct solution. Add an inline comment to drop the warning together with the reason why.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, analyzers are there to offer suggestions. Many of these suggestions might break the API, so they should always be considered carefully, especially when used in library code. In a *lot* of cases, even when using libraries: they are private and thus breaking the API: not a big issue, as the code is always deployed together; most hard breaks will be shown immediately simply by attempting to build the solution (or worst case: on the CI server). There is no right or wrong answer re breaking public APIs. If public API breaks *are* a genuine concern - typically for shared/published libraries, then that is more of a job for [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/PublicApiAnalyzers/PublicApiAnalyzers.Help.md).

If you don't like a particular analyzer result, yes you should suppress it locally (via one of the techniques you mention) or globally.